# WWDC scholarship

Tags: xcode

I submitted my WWDC Scholarship app and the first time I tried submitting it, it just logged me out. The second time it worked but my .app file was in the Xcode project, is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean your app was still located in the "Build" folder where Xcode put it, and you hadn't moved it out? I don't think the path to the app is part of the submission, and even if it is, Apple will figure it out.